# Bash convert character in variable

Tags: bash, collectd

I am writing a collectd nagios custom check script in bash. The problem I am having is that nagios shows hostnames as host.name.domain but collectd holds WSP files as host_name_domain. My question is how can I make a variable convert the hostname that it gets from nagios (host.name.domain) to collectd format (host_name_domain).

This is the part where the convertion has to occur. So the WSP_PATH would give out collectd format of hostname in variable $NHOST

```
WSP_PATH=/var/lib/carbon/whisper/ctd/$NHOST/uptime/uptime.wsp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sed:

```
$ NHOST="host.domain.tld"
$ NHOST=$(echo $NHOST | sed 's/\./-/g')
$ WSP_PATH=/var/lib/carbon/whisper/ctd/$NHOST/uptime/uptime.wsp
$ echo $WSP_PATH
/var/lib/carbin/whisper/ctd/host-domain/uptime/uptime.wsp
```

As above, /g is required so that all instances of . are replaced with -

Although on second thoughts, it would probably make more sense to perform this (sed) operation on the $NHOST variable (now edited to show this)

Comment: But it would be better to use sed on NHOST for sure. Because the sed at the moment would change the uptime.wsp to uptime-wsp and thats not what I would want. But this answer directed me to the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Quite right! Answer edited

Comment: For such single letter translations, you could also use `tr`: `NHOST=$(echo "$NHOST" | tr . _)`

Answer (score 13):

Bash has the required functionality built in (unless it's an ancient version):

```
WSP_PATH=/var/lib/carbon/whisper/ctd/${NHOST//./-}/uptime/uptime.wsp
```